# In the equation of wave (mechanical) : $y (x,t) = a \sin(kx-wt+\phi)$;

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

Does the $x$ show the displacement of the particle and the $y$ shows the displacement of the wave?

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right. For example in the example of a wave on a string, $x$ is the position along the length of the string and $y(x,t)$ is the displacement of the piece of string at that position at a given time.

[image]

[Image source](https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/AnalyzingWaves.htm)

The "particle" is the piece of string and never moves from that $x$ position, and only moves in the $y$ direction as described by the wave equation. Similarly in other waves like water waves, the actual particles of water don't move as the wave travels through them, only the "shape" of the wave and the energy it carries is actually moving along $x$.